# What magic happens in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have kotlin + spring boot app. I done some development in my feature branch committed and returned to dev branch, built app and just tried to start it in intellij idea, but get an error

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.test.Application, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I could swear it worked and moreover it works.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties()
class Application {

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Where i should look for reason of this issue - kotlin, intellij idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` function is a package-level (AKA ‘top-level’) function, because it's not defined within your `Application` class (or, more usually for `main()`, its `companion object`).

And in Kotlin/JVM, **package-level functions are treated as belonging to a special class named for the source file, with a `Kt` suffix.**

So in this case, you should specify the main class as `com.test.ApplicationKt`.

(The language docs describe this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions). This is one of those implementation details that you normally don't need to know; it's only important when specifying your main class, or calling a package-level function from Java.)